# How to add multiple empty columns to an empty data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have created an empty data frame `empty_df`, and want to add new columns of type `double()` with names `new_col_names`, to get `target_df` (empty data frame with old columns and new columns)

Clarification: The type does not matter, could also just be an empty colmn without a specified type if that is possible. I will assign some numeric vectors to those columns later on.

```
new_col_names <- c("A", "B", "C")

empty_df <- data.frame(col1 = as.Date(character()),
                       col2 = integer(),
                       col3 = double())

target_df <- data.frame(col1 = as.Date(character()),
                       col2 = integer(),
                       col3 = double(),
                       A = double(),
                       B = double(),
                       C = double())
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can run a for loop

```r
library(tidyverse)

new_col_names <- c("A", "B", "C")

empty_df <- data.frame(col1 = as.Date(character()),
                       col2 = integer(),
                       col3 = double())



for (names in new_col_names){
   empty_df[,names] <- double()
}

empty_df
#> [1] col1 col2 col3 A    B    C   
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I would avoid for loops when base R or the tidyverse provide perfectly good solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there. Just create a data.frame with your new columns, then cbind it:

```
empty_df <- data.frame(col1 = as.Date(character()),
                       col2 = integer(),
                       col3 = double())

newstuff_df <- data.frame(A = double(), 
                          B = double(), 
                          C = double())

target_df <- cbind(empty_df, newstuff_df)
```

If you really want a generic solution that feeds on a vector of column names of arbitrary length, you can go like this:

```
empty_df <- data.frame(col1 = as.Date(character(1)),  # we will need at least one row
                       col2 = integer(1),
                       col3 = double(1))

alt_df <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(new_col_names)))
colnames(alt_df) <- new_col_names

target_df <- cbind(empty_df, alt_df)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dplyr` package has `bind_cols`. Here's an example.

```
library(dplyr)
empty_df <- data.frame(col1 = as.Date(character()),
                                     col2 = integer(),
                                     col3 = double())
    
new_df <- data.frame(A = double(),
                                     B = double(),
                                     C = double())
    
result <- empty_df %>% dplyr::bind_cols(new_df)

result
#[1] col1 col2 col3 A    B    C   
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Answer (score 0):

one way to do this would be

```
for (i in new_col_names) empty_df[[i]] <- empty_df$col3
```

which sequentially adds the columns based on having the same class as one of the exisiting ones (`col3`).